# Convert a nested list to a list

Tags: r

I have a brief question, I would like to unnest this nested list:

```
mylist <- list(a = list(A=1, B=5), 
               b = list(C= 1, D = 2), 
               c = list(E = 1, F = 3))
```

Expected result is:

```
> list(a=c(1, 5), b = c(1, 2), c = c(1, 3))
$a
[1] 1 5

$b
[1] 1 2

$c
[1] 1 3
```

Any suggestions?

T

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at `llply` function from plyr package

```
> library(plyr)
> llply(mylist, unlist)
$a
A B 
1 5 

$b
C D 
1 2 

$c
E F 
1 3
```

If you want to get rid of the names, then try:

```
> lapply(llply(mylist, unlist), unname)
$a
[1] 1 5

$b
[1] 1 2

$c
[1] 1 3
```

Comment: Thanks @Jilber, although it is not the output which I looking for I can use it to build a data frame, many thanks

Comment: @user2380782, then maybe you could show what you are looking for, no?

Comment: @flodel, my output should be something similar to this `mylist2 <- list(a=c(1, 5), b = c(1, 2), c = c(1, 3))`

Comment: @user2380782 I edited my answer to give you the correct answer. If this is what you are looking for, then you can mark it as "correct"

Comment: no problem. Also `lapply(mylist, unlist, use.names = FALSE)`.

Comment: Great suggestion @flodel :) just R base solution!

Answer (score 5):

Slight variation on everyone else's and keeping it in base:

```
lapply(mylist, unlist, use.names=FALSE)

## $a
## [1] 1 5
## 
## $b
## [1] 1 2
## 
## $c
## [1] 1 3
```

Answer (score 0):

I think applying unlist() to each elment in your list should give you what you're looking for:

```
> mylist <- list(a = list(A=1, B=5), b = list(C= 1, D = 2), c = list(E = 1, F = 3))
> mylist2 <- list(a=c(1, 5), b = c(1, 2), c = c(1, 3))
> data.frame(lapply(mylist,unlist))
  a b c
A 1 1 1
B 5 2 3
> data.frame(mylist2)
  a b c
1 1 1 1
2 5 2 3
```