# How to unnest a list of lists of data frame in R?

Tags: r, tidyr, unnest

I have a rather complex list of lists of data frames that I want to unnest and make a simple data frame from, with each column representing a column in the nested data frames.  The data looks like this:

[image]

"percents" is the name of the entire list of 93 elements.  Each element is a list of 4 data frames, each with 19 variables.  Every time I try to unnest it, I get an error that says "no applicable method for unnest applied to an object of class list".  What do I have to do to get this to unnest itself?

Comment: Are you sure this hasn't been asked and answered multiple times? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16672645/convert-a-nested-list-to-a-list

Comment: Yes, that answer does not work for me, and I have checked several other questions.

Comment: reproducible example will really help - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: I do not see any reason why `do.call(rbind,  lapply(percents, function(chunks){ do.call( rbind, lapply(chunks, unlist)  ) }  ))` would not work. It appears to simple be a doubly nested list so doing the same opation twice should suffice. Prove me wrong by putting in a simple test case constructed with code.

Comment: That's what I just did before I saw your comment, and it's extremely fast and works.  do.call(cbind.data.frame, percents)

Comment: So you want these side by side rather than stacked. Same difference I suppose. You may need to adjust column names.